# Android change user position without recreating the path?

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation

I am creating user navigation application but,there is problem in change the user position. I have to create the path every time from origin to destination when user change the potion , but i don't want this. Actually i want output like Google navigation application as the person moving . Object is moving on the path.
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

So it is better option that if on map whenever you have long press click on map then that current marker is disappear and new marker create at a position where you Touch on map??